# Draw lines on div

Tags: javascript, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

I am using **draggable** to drag & drop icons on div. I can put icons on div & drag them easily. But I don't know how can I achieve the "Scribble" functionality (i.e., using mouse like pen to draw lines on div, like we can do on canvas).

Following is the sample code that I am trying to use:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>

              .dragContainer, .dragContainer2 {
                width:1100px;
                height:600px;            
                border: solid 1px green;
              }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("p").click(function () {
                $(this).hide();
            });
        });
        function AddIcon(lnk) {
            var icon = '<div class="draggable cross" class="ui-widget-content" style="position:absolute;">' +
                '<a href="#" onclick="CloseMe(this); return false;">X</a>' +
              '<p class="croxx"><img src="' + $(lnk).attr("data-icon-path") + '" alt="' + $(lnk).attr("data-icon-name") + '"/></p>' +
            '</div>';
            $(".dragContainer").append(icon);
            $(".draggable").draggable({
                scroll: false
            });
        }
    </script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <a title="test1" href="#" onclick="AddIcon(this); return false;" data-icon-path="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/Vista-Inspirate_1.0/64x64/apps/demo.png"><img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/Vista-Inspirate_1.0/64x64/apps/demo.png" alt="" /></a>

      <div class="dragContainer"> </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

If is there any way to achieve paint like functionality (drawing lines with mouse) with **draggable**.

Comment: Try this :http://jsfiddle.net/NWBV4/446/

Comment: @i_th your solution is using canvas but my requirement is to draw lines on dragger div, is this possible as i have tried this but no success?